# isometric tile selection formula is slightly off

Tags: python, selection, tile, pyglet, isometric

I almost made the isometric tile selection formula work but it seems to be slightly off: http://prntscr.com/pn3gbv

It seems to be working correctly when the mouse is hovered over the first half of the tile but it jumps to the next tile as the mouse is moved to the second half: http://prntscr.com/pn3hpx
 *([here's](https://youtu.be/MgwaJrilJrk) a video showing the issue)*.

It also doesn't account for a camera and I don't know how to implement that. So some help on that as well would be appreciated.

Below is the relevant code used, and [here's a minimal executable example](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/8b2e6d762307f5e14b02f73cc55ed65a) and also the image resource used:

[image: path.png]

```py
import pyglet

tile_width_half = 84/2
tile_height_half = 51/2

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.island = Island()
        self.camera = Camera()
        self.selection = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load("path.png"))
    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        global tile_height_half,tile_width_half
        j = int((x / tile_width_half + y / tile_height_half) / 2)
        i = int((y / tile_height_half - x / tile_width_half) / 2)
        self.selection.x = (j-i)*tile_width_half
        self.selection.y = (j+i)*tile_height_half
    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.island.draw()
        self.selection.draw()
    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.A:
            self.camera.left = True
        if symbol == key.W:
            self.camera.up = True
        if symbol == key.D:
            self.camera.right = True
        if symbol == key.S:
            self.camera.down = True
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE:
            pyglet.app.exit()
    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.A:
            self.camera.left = False
        if symbol == key.W:
            self.camera.up = False
        if symbol == key.D:
            self.camera.right = False
        if symbol == key.S:
            self.camera.down = False
    def update(self,dt):
        for tile in self.island.all_sprites:
            tile.x += self.camera.position[0]
            tile.y += self.camera.position[1]
        self.camera.move()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game(800,600,"title")
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(game.update,1/60)

    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/40b0dbcabccb8401d8b295097c6d5190) a minimal executable example. However, I would like to have the `path.png` sprite image you're using. A square isn't really going to work here for me.

Comment: It would be nice if you supplied `Island()` as well so we can render the backdrop.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't let me edit the original post so here's the link to island.py
https://gist.github.com/Anonymouswastaken/ff1c83f9c4082629c785d0714e6f70cc
and here's the link to tile images im using https://imgur.com/P1QVJqd https://imgur.com/hT5mdq7

Comment: I've made a short youtube clip about the issue showing/describing the problem a little better by modifying the "selection path" with blue color and a red rectangle. I'll have a look at the code a bit later :) But I think I know what the issue is hehe. Here's my version for the colored change and a full minimal executable example: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/d106ceb93c57c76159ff384374f1fee8 (You can copy paste and run this. I also added that into your question)

Comment: Thanks, I'd be so grateful if you found a solution